# Switching to Java from C++: What are the key points?

Tags: java, c++

I'm an experienced developer, but most of my OO programming experience has been with C++ (and a little Delphi). I'm considering doing some Android work, hence Java.

Coming from the C++ background, what areas of Java are most likely to surprise/annoy/delight me?

I felt sure this would already have been asked, but my searches haven't turned up a similar question.

CW, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**surprise:**

- Almost everything is on the heap
- It can be as fast as C++, even faster in a few cases
- The autoboxing of primitives *will* occasionally cause headaches

**annoy:**

- no unsigned integer types
- no preprocessor directives of any kind
- no operator overloading
- generics are castrated templates

**delight:**

- blessedly quick compilation
- No memory management
- No segfaults
- Most error conditions result in a stack trace that often pinpoints the problem
- Enums are *really* powerful
- A standardized, Unicode-aware String class

Comment: I would add that **almost everything is an object and they are manipulated by reference** and that **references are passed by value**. It usually helps C++ developers [a lot] to think of references as pointers that are automatically dereferenced.

Answer (score 7):

There's an excellent [article on wikipedia comparing the two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 3):

Just remember that in Java everything is a reference.  It seems so simple but as a C++ developer it will trip you up every time.

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the largest things coming from C++ is the lack of multiple inheritance.  Java compensates (and in the opinion of many, surpasses) multiple inheritance by focusing on Interfaces and object composition.

You'll be forced to think differently about your OO design, but the end result can often be cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: +1: Having learned Java after C++ myself, one of the two unexpected delights were the capabilities enabled by Interfaces (the other one was runtime reflection).

Answer (score 2):

If you use RAII, forget about it in Java.  Without knowing when an object will be deleted it is not possible.  Keep in mind when writing destructors that they could be executed well after your object goes out of scope.

Comment: Or they could just not be executed.  I've never quite figured out what a finalize method that might be called sooner, later, or never was good for.

Comment: @David - ironically you could probably use it to determine if the GC had just run - letting you know that anything time-sensitive is now in trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to care about memory
   allocation and deallocation.
2. No
   need to worry about assigning null
   to an object after its inception.
3. By
   default a simple declaration of
   object would have null as its value.
   Everything in Java is an object

Comment: except int, char, boolean, etc...

Comment: We have wrappers for primitives too, dont we?

Comment: Yes, there are wrappers for primitives, but there are primitives that are not objects.  It's an optimization that can have some unpleasant consequences if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 0):

The Peter Norton's Guide to Java Programming, ["Making the Transition from C/C++ to Java"](http://www.sheetudeep.com/res/javaapn/ch2.htm#MakingtheTransitionfromcctoJava) chapter.

Answer (score -1):

As I learn Java, I thought it would be useful to update this with my own comments:-

Delight:

- **Eclipse**! (Compared to C++ Builder, anyway...)
- **No header files**
- **No preprocessor**

Annoy:

- **Checked Exceptions.** Surely there's a compiler flag to disable
  these "errors"?
- **No RAII**. RAII
  does much, much more than just
  freeing memory. My code is going to
  be littered with "finallys", which I
  loathe.

More updates as I learn and appreciate more...

Comment: no header files can be an advantage, but I consider a disadvantage not being able to separate declaration from implementation for the public objects of your library.